# JavaFX 8 thread not stopping (intermittently) - how to always have it stop?

Tags: javafx-8

In my JavaFX desktop application I have the following code as the first line of the start method:

```
Platform.setImplicitExit(true);
```

My application uses several stages, and when the last one closes, I want the application thread to stop.  This is not always happening.  I can't find a pattern or a way to force it to close.

At times an exception may be the reason, but other times, there is no reason.  My application continues to show as a process on the Control Panel on Windows.

I am not really sure how else to force the app thread to stop?

Comment: You're unlikely to get help unless you can create an MCVE. Are you using any background threads?

Comment: Just for data retrieval. They don't process without a loader window running.

Comment: Best bet is one of the background threads is not exiting. Are you making those daemon threads?

Comment: I don't think I'm setting that specifically. But those processes did end before I close anything. But I'll give it a check if that helps. 9/10 times it always exits properly.

Comment: You could call `System.exit(0);` to enforce java shutting down.